# Image not getting displayed in IE 8

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, html, internet-explorer-8

I am having an image in div tag and I am expanding and collapsing that div tag.

When the `div` tag is expanded then the information is shown and when div tag is collapsed then the information is not shown.

Image is getting displayed properly in IE 9, Mozilla but in IE 8 it is not getting displayed.

I am adding image in `div` tag dynamically in code behind.

My code is as follows

```
String expandDivId = String.Format("{0}", "testkey");
StringBuilder testLinks = new StringBuilder();

testLinks.Append(String.Format("<div><a href='#' id='" + expandDivId + "-or" + "  onclick='javascript:ExpandInfo(\"" + expandDivId + "\"); return false;'>{0}</a></div>", "TestTitle")); 

testLinks.Append(String.Format("<div style='display: none;' id='{0}'>", expandDivId));

testLinks.Append("<div class=\"head1\" style=\"font-weight:bold\">Test Informaton</div>");

testLinks.Append("<div style=\"text-align:left;\">Test data and informaion.<br /><br /></div>");

testLinks.Append("<a href='http://www.forums.asp.net' target='blank'>test heading 1</a>&nbsp;<img src=\"../../images/TestIcon.png\" alt=\"PDF\" width=\"14\" nowrap/><br/>");

testLinks.Append("</div>");
```

My javascript function is as follows

```
function ExpandInfo(divId) {
    var origin = $("#" + divId + "-or");
    if ($(origin).hasClass("ex")) {
        $(origin).text($(origin).text().slice(0, -1) + "+");
    } else {
        $(origin).text($(origin).text().slice(0, -1) + "-");
    }    
    $("#" + divId).slideToggle("500");
    $(origin).toggleClass("ex");
}
```

Please let me know why the image is not getting displayed in IE 8.

Comment: What language is your back-end code in?

Answer (score -1):

You need to add a height attribute. An img element is technically invalid without one, but most browsers will work it out. IE8 (predictably, perhaps) just assumes your image has no height at all, and so doesn't appear to display it.

Comment: A height attribute is NOT invalid without one, technically or otherwise, and ALL browsers work without one. In fact, such attributes have been deprecated entirely. http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/objects.html#h-13.7 The browser will get size information from the image and use that to display the image.

Comment: Good call, @Rob – I wasn't aware they had been depreciated. It's still relevant to IE8, though - without the dimensions attribute, the old dog doesn't reserve any space for the image. So if you need to support oldIE, it's best to stick with them for the time being and override using stylesheets if that's appropriate.